# Is there a way to physically manifest healing magics?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, healing

In (D&D 5E) where there is going to be an ability check to escape a situation (during a chase, perhaps) could a play with the use of healing magics physically manifest to make a slippery area on the ground?  Sort of like in Brent Weeks' books with color magic.
**What spells would have a better chance of breaking the barrier of not so much with the rules, but just outside the thought realm of normal spell casting in D&D?**
 I have read through a huge amount of spells seeking for some that might fit the description. I do not see any that fit as much as I want I suppose.

Comment: All of that is correct aside form it being of any specific character just yet. I am devising ways to escape a very perilous journey though a large cave, and when exhausting all options, and if they get stuck I want to be able to hint towards using their abilities, healing being the first example, to  catch an enemy off guard. Hindering movement of some sort. And maybe using a damage spell outside of combat. Like in the brent weeks' lightbringer series, the luxin, their magic manifestation,  can be slippery liquid, explosive goop, flexible rubber like substance and what not.

Comment: In short, I do not know what spell or race, etc. will use it yet. More so being a what if situation.

Comment: That may make for a difficult-to-answer question in the SE format.  With the magic system you describe, and the magic system in the 5e game system, it may be difficult to get the two fictions to mix.  Are you looking for an answer that uses the 5e rules and magic system to create these effects?  Idea generation may be better resolved on [a discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566).

Comment: YEs actually, that is what i am asking. What spells would have a better chance of breaking the barrier of not so much with the rules, but just outside the thought realm of normal spell casting in d&d. I have read thought a huge amount of spells seeking for some that might fit the description. I do not see any that fit as much as I want i suppose.

Comment: I will do just that. Also thank you for helping and sifting as well. I am still extremely new to d&d. Making my questions probably seem far fetched. Shoot, I barely understand the dice. I am just so excited to get all of this started that I am way over my head. I've even made backstories for villains my players might see once. lol

Comment: Best wishes, and happy gaming! :)

Comment: I’m sorry, but “what spells break the barriers of the thought realm” is both confusing and way too broad to answer - players have tried something “out of the box” with pretty much every spell ever.

Answer (score 5):

*Dungeons & Dragons* magic takes after the works of Jack Vance, where magic came in very discrete spells that did very specific things. Vancian mages have to memorize preposterously precise arcane formulae and patterns in order to create magic at all—even the slightest change can cause the spell to fizzle to nothing.

So *Dungeons & Dragons* is not a system that tends to allow spells to be used in wildly different ways from what they’re intended. Some spells are intentionally flexible, and of course tricks and combos happen, but for the most part when you learn or prepare a spell, you have *that spell’s effect* and not any other effect. Learning and/or preparing *cure wounds* means you don’t have *grease*—or, equivalently, to be able to slick the floor like you suggest, you need to know and/or prepare *grease*, which may mean you don’t have *cure wounds*. That’s a big part of the challenge of playing a spellcaster in *Dungeons & Dragons*.

There are ways to be more flexible. Sorcerers, in D&D 5e, are notable for modifying their magic quite a bit—that’s their thing. But you’ll notice that even sorcerers still cannot go so far as to change a healing spell to a slippery spell.

Prior editions of *Dungeons & Dragons* have also included ways for spellcasters to swap their spells on the fly. For example, clerics in 3e could trade any spell they prepared for a *cure wounds* spell (or *inflict wounds* spell, for evil clerics) of the same level. Druids could swap for a *summon nature’s ally* spell. (Note that in this edition, spellcasters who prepared spells didn’t just have to prepare *which* spells, but also *how many of each*, so these were pretty decent benefits.) And other classes and feats allowed more flexibility with that kind of thing—a wizard could favor a particular spell, or a sorcerer could learn to swap spells for a spell off a list of the same level.

In D&D 5e, with its changes to how spellcasting works, you don’t need that explicit “swap” though. It ends up being the same as just another spell prepared (or learned), so Wizards of the Coast refers to it that way. The cleric, rather than always have *cure wounds* prepared (which would be the direct translation of the 3e version), instead always has domain spells prepared. That is basically the same as saying that, for example, you can always swap the *cure wounds* you prepared for the spell off the domain list. If you had a domain that offered *grease* as a spell, then you really would be using your healing magical energy to slick the floor (or, at least, could validly describe your cleric as doing so).

Anyway, we can be pretty confident that D&D 5e’s magic will never look like the magic in the works of Brent Weeks. Both the Night Angel trilogy and the Black Prism series focus on magic that is highly mutable and flexible, and that just doesn’t fit with the Vancian style that *Dungeons & Dragons* uses. Other, non-*Dungeons & Dragons* systems, do offer magic like that, though it is beyond the scope of this answer (or this site) to offer recommendations there, so you’ll have to do some of your own research.

Comment: I double checked Trickery and Arcana domains, and that spell (grease) isn't on either domain list. (A DM could add it, though ...)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Oh yeah, I didn’t mean to imply such a domain *actually existed*, just that if it did it would probably be the best you could do for this kind of thing in D&D 5e.

Comment: Seems to me a productive area for DM making a fit, and I'd say Trickery is the perfect domain for that ... or even something like a Clown domain>  :)